# How to multiply value of a stringVar()?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, variable-assignment, calculation

Good morning everyone !

I would like to ask if somebody know how is it possible to **multiply the value from a StringVar()**

```
        value = tk.StringVar()
        value.set(1)

        def multiply():

           scales_value = value.get()
           label.config(text=selection * 100)

        scale = Scale(command=multiply,
                      variable=value)
```

With this method it returns me with 1 for example ;

**1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1...100 times**

but I would like it returns me **100**

> S  O  L  U  T  I  O  N ;

**I had to use DoubleVar() instead of StringVar() with Scale(from_=0.01, to=1)**

```
        value = tk.DoubleVar()
        value.set(1)

        def multiply():

           scales_value = value.get()
           label.config(text=selection * 100)

        scale = Scale(command=multiply,
                      from_=0.01, to=1,
                      variable=value)
```

Why DoubleVar()?

IntVar() was also a good solution for this example if we add from_1 to 100 in Scale();

```
        value = tk.IntVar()
        value.set(1)

        def multiply():

           scales_value = value.get()
           label.config(text=selection * 100)

        scale = Scale(command=multiply,
                      from_=1, to=100,
                      variable=value)
```

But problem is that scale() will not count decimals, so if you have to work with numbers<1 , it will returns 0

**Thanks for you answers !**

Comment: Use `tk.IntVar()` instead.

Comment: Hint: `'2'*10` -> `'2222222222'`.  `int('2') * 10` -> `20`, but yeah, use `tk.IntVar()` :)

Comment: Thanks, I would like to use IntVar() but for some reason it doesn't works with Scale() value returns 0 ^^'

Comment: `variable=value` should be used instead.

Comment: Ah yes sorry I update !I made a mistake in my example, but issue will be still there

Comment: Ok I found the problem, I had to use DoubleVar() ! Thank you all for answers :) !